# how to pop up a form inside a div and carry the id

Tags: html, popup, window

I have a form inside a div how to make it popup and also carry the id (if the form is in edit mode) when it is popped up? thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you want a div to popup? You mean that you want to open a new browser window containing that div?

Comment: Refer http://fancybox.net/ to create popup

Comment: Hi Max, yes. in normal popup usually call another html page, but I see these days it doesn't call it. the popped up window is actually a div inside that html page.

Comment: solved by implementing jqgrid